# Concatenate Columns and Create a Composite Key from a Text File in Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed

I have been trying to implement a Feature in my Shell Script but somehow stuck in implementation, need help please.

```
Sample File - f1.txt

col1|col2|col3|rev|spt
A1|54|tyre|56.89|45.23
B1|54|pole|11.89|85.23
C1|54|ture|112.89|185.23
```

The Files can have any number of Columns and it is not fixed.
What i want to achive is ->

```
Concatenate all the Columns in the File (Note- It can have any number of Columns) except the Columns- rev and spt

Whenever it Finds Column Name as rev or spot it shouldnot include in Concatenation.
Example-

Output-
KeyCol|rev|spot
A1~54~tyre|56.89|45.23
B1~54~pole|11.89|85.23
C1~54~ture|112.89|185.23
```

So ideally i want to create a Composite in any file having any number of columns except the columns named rev and spot.

Please help

Comment: Is has to be according to the column name? Those columns can appear anywhere at the table, not necessarily as the last two fields?

Comment: the columns rev and spt always will be at the last 2 fields thats for sure, but other than that the rest columns can be any number of columns which i have to create a composite key

Comment: rev and spt column names will never change but OTHER column names can be different in different files @aviro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` command you can use:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1 {OFS=FS; print "KeyCol", $(NF-1), $NF} NR > 1 {OFS="~"; LAST=$(NF-1) FS $NF; NF-=2; print $0 FS LAST}'
```

##### Explanation

- `-F '|'` means the input field separator is `|`.
- `NR==1` means that operate only the first line. On the first line, print only "KeyCol" for the first field, and then the last two fields, and the `OFS` (the Output Field Separator) would be `FS` (the Input Field Separator), which is in your case, `|`.
- On next next line after the first (`NR > 1`):

  - `OFS="~"` means the new Output Field Separator would be `~`.
  - `LAST=$(NF-1) FS $NF` - Save the last two fields in a string variable called `LAST`, and sperate them by the `FS` (the Input Field Separator).
  - `NF-=2` - Decrease the number of fields (`NF`) by 2 to exclude the last two fields.
  - `print $0 FS LAST`

    - `$0` now holds only the first (NF-2) fields.
    - It will print them separated by the `OFS` (in this case, `~`
    - Followed by the original `FS` (which is `|`)
    - And the variable LAST that holds the last two fields.

##### Output

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1 {OFS=FS; print "KeyCol", $(NF-1), $NF} NR > 1 {OFS="~"; LAST=$(NF-1) FS $NF; NF-=2; print $0 FS LAST}' f1.txt
KeyCol|rev|spt
A1~54~tyre|56.89|45.23
B1~54~pole|11.89|85.23
C1~54~ture|112.89|185.23
```

##### Note 1

You can move the the `OFS="~"` line to the end of `NR==1` line, because then it would apply on all the next records and you won't need to set it for every line.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1 {OFS=FS; print "KeyCol", $(NF-1), $NF; OFS="~"} NR > 1 {LAST=$(NF-1) FS $NF; NF-=2; print $0 FS LAST}'
```

##### Note 2

You could create an awk script to automate it.

```
$ cat composite.awk
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
NR == 1 {
  OFS=FS
  print "KeyCol", $(NF-1), $NF
  OFS="~"
} 
NR > 1 {
  LAST=$(NF-1) FS $NF
  NF-=2
  print $0 FS LAST
}
```

Notice I added a `BEGIN` section where I set the `FS`, so you wouldn't need the `-F '|'` arguments to the `awk` command.

And then run it using the script file.

```
$ awk -f composite.awk f1.txt                                                                                            
KeyCol|rev|spt
A1~54~tyre|56.89|45.23
B1~54~pole|11.89|85.23
C1~54~ture|112.89|185.23
```